# How can i use Extent report with puppeteer-Jest automation similar to Selenium

Tags: ui-automation, selenium-extent-report, jest-puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer for UI automation with jest Framework.
i had worked previously selenium and used extend report i want similar kind of reporting with puppeteer.
Is there a way i can use extent report or do we have some similar reporting for puppeteer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is not available out of the box. Reason for this can be found in the fact that Selenium is more oriented toward testing while and contains more tools while Puppeteer is more focused on being remote control library.

I suggest using some 3rd party library like `jest-html-reporter` (https://github.com/Hargne/jest-html-reporter#readme) or `jest-html-reporters` (https://github.com/Hazyzh/jest-html-reporters). The other alternative would be generating your own HTML report manually in JS code from Puppeteer command results and outcomes.

Comment: thanks, do you have any more documentation how can we customize the report apart from github and npm docs
i have used Hazyzh/jest-html-reporters for reference